# Pass Complex Parameters using Http.GetAsync

Tags: c#

how do i pass two complex parameters, say two class objects, when i call HttpClient.GetAsync ?

I understand we could add it along the url if its simple parameters like string. But when it is complex ones such as class, how do we do it ?

Comment: Well what would you want the URL to look like? What's the server expecting? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: am sorry, if the Server Method is expecting 2 complex parameters, for example. Method(Class1 obj1,Class2 obj2).

Comment: No, the server will be expecting an HTTP request. You need to work out what that request should look like.

Answer (score 1):

use HttpClient.PostAsync

if you want to send complex data, and not just simple string

also on the server side, check if the api accepts post requests

you can test requests using http://Hurl.it